# toString method is not showing anything when i run the code

Tags: java, class, object

`toString` method is not showing anything when I run the code:

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private String firstName, lastname, socialSecurityNumber;



 Employee(){

    System.out.println("Employee Constructor called");
    firstName="Tony";
    lastname="Stark";
    socialSecurityNumber="3000";
}


    public String getFirstName(){
        System.out.println(firstName);
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }
    public String getSocialSecurityNumber(){
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }


    public String toString(){

     getSocialSecurityNumber();
     getLastname();
     getFirstName();

        return null;
    }
}

//Main method:
public void ComissionEmployeeTest(){

    Employee checkFirstly=new ComissionEmloyee();
checkFirstly.toString();

}
```

Comment: How is `toString` overridden in `ComissionEmloyee`?

Comment: getSocialSecurityNumber(); and the other ones returns a String, but that doesn't mean it's going to be displayed on the console. You need to log it.

Comment: You are not even printing it so how do you want to see anything? You just call the method and you do not do anything with the returned value.

Comment: `toString()` method is meant to return a `String` representation of the object. But you're returning a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your toString() is returns a null. You need to return a String instead.

Example

```
public String toString(){
  return String.format("ssn %s firstname %s lastname %s",getSocialSecurityNumber() + getLastname() + getFirstName());
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(firstName);` is printed in `getFirstName()`, so whilst you method in correct it does answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Your toString method should be

```
public String toString(){

 return getSocialSecurityNumber()+
 getLastname()+
 getFirstName();

}
```

and you should nbe printing the same to see the value

```
System.out.println(checkFirstly);
```

Comment: `System.out.println(firstName);` is printed in `getFirstName()`, so whilst you method in correct it does answer the question

Answer (score 0):

When you call that `toString();` method, you are getting always `null` as return.
With your method, doing `System.out.println(e.toString());` is always the same as doing `System.out.println(null);`.
So you need to return the String, concatnated, composed with the variables. For example:

Modify the toString method like:

```
public String toString(){
    //You can customize this as you wish
    return "SN: " + getSocialSecurityNumber() + " Last name: " etLastname() + " First name: " +getFirstName();

}
```

and call it like:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
System.out.println(e.toString());
```

**Edit**

I see you have a output on the firstName getter, so doing `new Empoyee().toString();` should at least output something.

Comment: `System.out.println(firstName);` is printed in `getFirstName()`, so whilst you method in correct it does answer the question

Comment: @ScaryWombat We don't even have the code which is running and instatiating the class.